# Regex for Matching All Strings That Contain Two Different Words from a List

Tags: java, regex

I have need for a regular expression (in Java) that matches a string if and only if it contains two **different** words from a given list.

For example, if the list of words is {blue,yellow,pink}, then the strings "blue and pink" and "yellow is the new blue" will match, but the strings "I like blue" will not (only one word from the list appears) and neither will the string "My pink shirt is so very pink" (it does not contain two or more different words, but the same word twice).

The closest I could get to my desired regex is:

`(.(blue|yellow|pink).){2}`

This regex will match any string that contains two or more words from the list, but it will do so even if the two words are the same (as in the "My pink shirt is so very pink" example).

Thanks!!

Answer (score 4):

After capturing the initial word, repeat characters and negative lookahead for the first capture group right before matching the second color-word alternations:

```
.*(blue|yellow|pink).*(?!\1)(blue|yellow|pink).*
```

https://regex101.com/r/OPo2bf/1

Comment: I like this one, better than mine, obvoiously :)

Answer (score 1):

You could do it with two lookaheads

```
^(?=.*blue)(?=.*pink).+$
```

But you'll need to specifiy the words programmatically before. See [**a demo on regex101.com**](https://regex101.com/r/04CR2Z/1/).

Answer (score 1):

You might use a positive lookahead and a capturing group with an anchor to assert the start and the end of the string and use a capturing group with a backreference to assert what is on the right is not what is already captured:

```
^(?=.*(blue|yellow|pink).*(?!\1)(blue|yellow|pink)).*$
```

Demo on [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/qkcpBZ/1)